# How to create vector of matrices to store large number of images?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, matrix

I want to create the vector of matrices to stores as many images as possible.

I know that,it is possible as written below:

```
vector<Mat> images1;
```

and during the image acquisition from the camera and i would save the images at 100fps with resolution of 1600*800 as below:

```
images1.push_back(InputImage.clone());
```

Where `InputImage` is the Mat and given by the camera. Since creating video during the acquisition process either leads to frame missing in the video or reduction in aquisition speed.

Later after stopping the image acquisition and before stopping the program, I would write the images into video as written below:

```
VideoWriter writer;
writer = Videowriter("video.avi",-1,100,frameSize(1600,800),false);
for (vector<Mat>::iterator iter = images1.begin(); ier != images1.end(); iter++)
writer.write(*iter);
```

Is it correct, since I am not sure the `images1` can store the images around 1500 images without overflow.

Comment: Do the maths. At 24 bits per pixel, you're looking at a bit less than 6 GB.

Comment: Consider using `reserve` up-front if you know your total number of images you want to store so that you aren't trying to reallocate inside a 100fps loop.

Comment: Why do you essentially _have_ to use a Vector? What about other STL containers?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to worry about "overflow", whatever that means in your context.

The bigger problem is memory. A single frame takes (at 8 bits per color, with 3 colors) `3 * 1600 * 800 == 3.84Mb`. At 100fps, One second of footage requires 0.384Gb of memory. 8GB of memory can only hold about 20 seconds of footage. You'll need almost 24GB of memory before you can hold a whole minute. There's a reason that the vast, vast, **vast** majority of Video Encoding Software only keeps a few frames of video data in memory at any given time, and dumps the rest to the hard drive (or discards it, depending on what purpose the software is serving).

What you should probably be doing (which is what programs like FRAPS do) is dumping frames to the hard drive as soon as soon as you receive them. Then, when recording finishes, you can either call it a day (if raw video footage is what you need) or you can begin a process of reading the file and encoding it into a more compressed format.

Comment: but my image is grey scale image so it needs 3.84/3 =  1.28 Mb so at 100 fps for 1 second it is 0.128Gb of memory. If i want to record for 20 seconds which is 2.56 Gb. For my case a recording of 20 fps is good enough.

Comment: @reddy2810 look, if you live in a world where you know for certain that you have all the memory you need, then your approach is probably fine. The advice I've given is tailored for more realistic scenarios where you know you'll need the program to scale to larger video feeds.

Comment: ok. I work with GigE PRO camera and i could not find the software for recording the videos at 100 fps with this resolution and moreover i posted this looking for some one who could help me in implementation of it via coding using vector<mat> or something else

Answer (score 0):

Pre-allocate your image vector in memory so that you just need to copy the frames without real-time allocation.

If you have memory problems, try dumping the frames to a file, the OS will hopefully be able to handle the I/O. If not try memory mapped files.

Comment: for pre-allocation i tried vector of reserve but it does not work with Mat as it works in int. It gives me syntax error.

Comment: Pre allocation means resizing the vector (not reserve) or push_backing clones into it.